# oracledb getConnection is not a function in node js

Tags: node.js

> oracledb.getConnection is not a function in node js

Already did:

`npm install oracledb`

Can someone please help?

```
 async  tidInfoSubmitForm(){
  let connection;
    const oracledb = require('oracledb');
    const config = {
      user : 'XX',
      password : 'XX',
      connectString : "XXX"
    }
    try {
    connection = await  oracledb.getConnection(config);
    
    const result = await connection.execute('Select * from table',
    function (err :any, result :any) {
     console.log(result.rows);
    });
   } catch 
    (err) {
      alert(err)
     console.log('Error :' + err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Edit your question and addmore detail.  Is this running in pure Node.js, or in something like Electron?  What OS? What versions?  How did you install the Oracle client libraries?

Comment: Pure Node js ; v 14.16.1 ; npm install oracledb ; windows

Comment: Are you using Typescript?

Comment: yes with node js

Comment: Details matter.  Please update your question with relevant info about the tech you are using, and the versions of it.  At a guess, you might be seeing https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1408  If so, please test the patch and let us know if it helps.